# Telegram webapp клавиатура

Tags: telegram, клавиатура

У нас есть webapp в телеграм боте , с телеграм ссылками на участников, после клика на ссылку
( как я понял webview сварачивается в бекграунд),
мы переходим в чат к участнику.
По клику по стрелке назад в верхнем левом углу(android, ios устройство),
мы возвращаемся в webapp, на ту страницу с которой перешли в чат.
Далее,когда двигаемся по разделам webapp,все текстовые поля для ввода не активны(не вызывается клавиатура).
Нет фокуса на формах ввода. Через дебаг  я отследил что событие клика отрабатывает,
событие фокуса также работает, но клавиатуру не активируется.
Взаимодействие через debug с клавиатурой не дало никаких результатов.
Жду ваших мыслей.